# Why is variable showing up as undefined?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am using flask to create a webform on http://localhost:5000/ and my goal is for the form to prompt the user for two inputs, then write those inputs into two new python3 files named test2.py and test3.py. The variable 'text' and 'text1' keep coming up as undefined. Here is the code and its error:

code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('my-form.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    text = request.form['text']
    text1 = request.form['text1']

with open('test2.py', 'w+') as file:
    file.write(text)

with open('test3.py', 'w+') as file:
    file.write(text1)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 15, in <module>
    file.write(text)
      NameError: name 'text' is not defined
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is because `text` and `text1` are defined in the function, while file handling is outside. The file handling should be inside the post method.